# Trying to fix leaky faucet but can’t find set screw

Tags: plumbing-fixture, leaking

[image]

This hole is in the back and impossible to see what’s inside???

Comment: It's probably an allen set screw. Can you post what brand the faucet is. With that info someone might be able to tell you the exact size.

Comment: Adding a flashlight to using your phone camera can be a good modern way to see things that are otherwise hard to see. Old-fashioned way, use a mirror, but the phone camera can get useful magnification if you can get light in the hole and focus on it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an Allen Wrench to loosen the set screw. They are sold in sets of right angled wrenches and several varying sizes. There are metric and SAE sized also.

Faucet set screws are usually SAE and sized towards the smaller end of the wrench sizes.

Comment: I'm going to try the allen wrenches today. There is no brand name on the faucet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was a Kohler brand faucet and I was able to fix this one. Unfortunately there is a second faucet needing repair but whoever installed it stripped the set screw :(. Can't use a drill. May try to use a rubber band on tip of Allen wrench to get some grip. Any other suggestions??

Comment: Yes. try this:use a small slotted screw driver. also try the tang (handle) of a file. Sometimes a drill bit works. There are extractor bits that grip the screw head when turning it to loosen.

Comment: As a final hail mary loosen the nut holding the faucet in place and you'll be able to turn it towards you to facilitate work.